# My Qt Creator IDE starts to type in Chinese instead of English

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am working on Qt Quick application in Qt Creator. My help was not working (F1) key and I pressed some keys like CTRL + F1 etc. All of sudden my Qt Creator types chinese when edit code which is very annoying. Of course I can't write any code now. I have attached a picture. I was writing "Red" but it writes Chinese and brings up menu was as well in chinese which I don't what what is about.P[image]lease help!

Comment: Which input method are you using?

Comment: @xgdgsc I don't know what does that mean, I am using keyboard and English? However I got it fixed by deleting Qt Creator setting files.

Comment: The files are here <drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject and <drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\QtProject.